# Save results in xlsx file of loop function

Tags: matlab, function, xlsxwriter

I am testing various segmentation algorithms in order to compare their results.In order to do this i have specific algorithms that count the objects present in each image after the segmentation process. Then as i have one big image dataset it's very tiring to manually register all the count result values of each image segmentation. I'm trying to implement the XLSWRITE function from matlab to automate the process, but not having much success....

One of the segmentation methods that I am using is the hough transform to find circles, you can see the code here:

```
    clear all, clc;

a=1:35;
A = arrayfun( @(x) sprintf( '%04d', x ), a, 'UniformOutput', false );
I = cellfun( @(b) imread( ['C:Teste/' b '/c1/' b '.png'] ), A, 'UniformOutput', false );

for i = a
    % Gaussian Filter
    W = fspecial('gaussian',[10,10],2);
    J = imfilter(I,W);

    % Finding Circular objects -- Houng Transform
    [centers, radii, metric] = imfindcircles(J,[5 10], 'Sensitivity',0.93,'Edge',0.27); 
    %[radius_parasites]=[5 10] 'Sensitivity',0.93,'Edge',0.27)
    %[radius_nucleus]=[10 20] 'Sensitivity',0.87,'Edge',0.27)

    idx_mask = ones(size(radii));

    min_dist = 2; % relative value.
    for i = 2:length(radii)
        cur_cent = centers(i, :);
        for j = 1:i-1
            other_cent = centers(j,:);
            x_dist = other_cent(1) - cur_cent(1);
            y_dist = other_cent(2) - cur_cent(2);
            if sqrt(x_dist^2+y_dist^2) < min_dist*(radii(i) + radii(j)) && idx_mask(j) == 1
                idx_mask(i) = 0;
                break
            end
        end
    end

    idx_mask = logical(idx_mask);
    centers_use = centers(idx_mask, :);
    radii_use = radii(idx_mask, :);
    metric_use = metric(idx_mask, :);

    viscircles(centers_use, radii_use,'EdgeColor','b');
    a=length(centers_use)
end
```

So I would like to save the variable `a` in one column with a header cell for the 35 images that I have (loop each image) like this:

```
      Results_Al_1
     -------------
      a1
      a2
        ...
```

For this i was trying to do this:

```
filename = 'testdata.xlsx';
A = {'Al_1';'Results of Al 1';a};
sheet = 1;
xlRange = 'B1';
xlswrite(filename,A,sheet,xlRange)
```

So if anyone could help me out I would really appreciate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which data you actually want to save? Please edit the expected behaviour description in your question so it reflects exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi Matt, yah i revise and understand your point... The variable that i want to save in each loop is the a... its a simple object count at the end of the code. Thanks!